# dictionary inside of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries which looks like this:

```
response = [{'startIndex': 0,
  'destinationIndex': 0,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 2797, 'costFactor': 2884}},
 {'startIndex': 0,
  'destinationIndex': 1,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 3686, 'costFactor': 4541}},
 {'startIndex': 0,
  'destinationIndex': 2,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 3391, 'costFactor': 3979}},
 {'startIndex': 0,
  'destinationIndex': 3,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 3082, 'costFactor': 3244}},
 {'startIndex': 1,
  'destinationIndex': 0,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 0, 'costFactor': 1}},
 {'startIndex': 1,
  'destinationIndex': 1,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 1103, 'costFactor': 2656}},
 {'startIndex': 1,
  'destinationIndex': 2,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 808, 'costFactor': 2094}},
 {'startIndex': 1,
  'destinationIndex': 3,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 676, 'costFactor': 1595}},
 {'startIndex': 2,
  'destinationIndex': 0,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 1543, 'costFactor': 3152}},
 {'startIndex': 2,
  'destinationIndex': 1,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 0, 'costFactor': 1}},
 {'startIndex': 2,
  'destinationIndex': 2,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 1496, 'costFactor': 3043}},
 {'startIndex': 2,
  'destinationIndex': 3,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 1489, 'costFactor': 3106}},
 {'startIndex': 3,
  'destinationIndex': 0,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 1208, 'costFactor': 2484}},
 {'startIndex': 3,
  'destinationIndex': 1,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 1377, 'costFactor': 2807}},
 {'startIndex': 3,
  'destinationIndex': 2,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 0, 'costFactor': 1}},
 {'startIndex': 3,
  'destinationIndex': 3,
  'summary': {'travelTime': 624, 'costFactor': 1378}}]
```

As you may see, one of the keys of the dictionaries (`summary`) is also a dictionary. What I want to do is to pass all dictionaries into a pandas dataframe. I am trying to use the following code to do that:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response, orient = 'columns')
```

However I am getting this output:

```
startIndex  destinationIndex                                   summary
0                 0           {'travelTime': 2966, 'costFactor': 3053}
0                 1           {'travelTime': 3868, 'costFactor': 4723}
0                 2           {'travelTime': 3573, 'costFactor': 4161}
0                 3           {'travelTime': 3164, 'costFactor': 3326}
1                 0           {'travelTime': 0, 'costFactor': 1}
1                 1           {'travelTime': 1114, 'costFactor': 2667}
1                 2            {'travelTime': 819, 'costFactor': 2105}
1                 3            {'travelTime': 676, 'costFactor': 1595}
2                 0           {'travelTime': 1543, 'costFactor': 3152}
2                 1                 {'travelTime': 0, 'costFactor': 1}
2                 2           {'travelTime': 1496, 'costFactor': 3043}
2                 3           {'travelTime': 1489, 'costFactor': 3106}
3                 0           {'travelTime': 1208, 'costFactor': 2484}
3                 1           {'travelTime': 1377, 'costFactor': 2807}
3                 2                 {'travelTime': 0, 'costFactor': 1}
3                 3            {'travelTime': 624, 'costFactor': 1378}
```

My first two columns are ok but in my third column I have a dictionary where `travelTime` and `costFactor` are the keys. What I want to do is to "create" new columns with those keys so my final df should look like this:

[image]

If anyone has any idea about how to do that I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: ``pd.json_normalize(response)`` ?

Comment: I am getting this error: `module 'pandas' has no attribute 'json_normalize'`

Comment: what version of pandas are you on? maybe upgrade to the latest. or, depending on your version, import : ``from pandas import json_normalize``

Comment: It worked! I used `from pandas import json_normalize` and then `new_df =  json_normalize(response)` Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't upgrade to use `pd.json_normalize` you update your current result like so:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response, orient = 'columns')
for col in ["travelTime", "costFactor"]:
    new_df[col] = new_df["summary"].str.get(col)

new_df = new_df.drop(columns="summary")
print(new_df)
    startIndex  destinationIndex  travelTime  costFactor
0            0                 0        2797        2884
1            0                 1        3686        4541
2            0                 2        3391        3979
3            0                 3        3082        3244
4            1                 0           0           1
5            1                 1        1103        2656
6            1                 2         808        2094
7            1                 3         676        1595
8            2                 0        1543        3152
9            2                 1           0           1
10           2                 2        1496        3043
11           2                 3        1489        3106
12           3                 0        1208        2484
13           3                 1        1377        2807
14           3                 2           0           1
15           3                 3         624        1378
```